# knockout depandent variables: how to define structure properly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to Knockout, and I have the following question:

I have Ids coming from database and each Id has its corresponding Description (this is actualy  enum in .NET, but I do not think this is important in this question).

For example,

a) for variable "`PType`": `0 - Undefined; 1 - Low Structure; 2 - Hight Structure`
b) for variable "`ClientType`": `0 - Undefined, 1 - P Type; 2 - S Type` 
etc. for some other variables also

How to properly define model for this dependency?
Currently I have only Ids like

```
PType: ko.observable();
ClientType: ko.observable();
```

and I show Ids on page:

```
<span data-bind="text: PType"></span>
<span data-bind="text: ClientType"></span>
```

However, I need to have something like: `PTypeDescription` and `ClientTypeDescription` to show for User. I believe that those are somehow dependant variables, but cannot get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i 'll suppose that you already know what enums you have and when you get data via AJAX, you get enums value represented as `integer` not `string`

You can simulate enums in Javascript easily (check [this article](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/Creating-Javascript-Enum-values.aspx)):

```
var PType = { 0: "Undefined", 1: "Low Structure", 2: "Hight Structure" }
var ClientType = { 0: "Undefined", 1: "P Type", 2: "S Type" }
```

So, your view-model can be something like:

```
var itemObj = {
    PType: ko.observable(0);
    ClientType: ko.observable(0);
    property1:ko.observable('')// put here the other properties if you have more
}
```

To get your enum represnted as enum you write call function that takes the `value`("your enum key") and which enum to use("you can use inline function for that").

***[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P3WrG/1/)***

**Update**
Check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286899/javascript-enum-to-corresponding-string-value#4286951) to another implementaion for Enums in JS, it's simple and effective