# Generic key value for interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, interface

I want to create an interface with generic keys limited by, say an enum, ensuring that the interface only accept certain keys and values.

I imagine doing something like this

```
interface IFruit<TargetKey extends string, TargetValue> {
  [key: TargetKey]: TargetValue;
}
```

Where the interface could be defined using the following:

```
enum Keys {
  APPLES = 'APPLES',
  ORANGES = 'ORANGES',
}

enum Values {
  GREEN = 'GREEN',
  BLUE = 'BLUE',
  ORANGE = 'ORANGE',
}

const test: IFruit<Keys, Values> = {
  Keys.APPLES: Values.GREEN,
  'POTATOES': 'BLUE', // Should give an error, as key is not in Keys enum
}
```

I'm not sure if this is possible to even achieve. So far I get an index signature error `An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'`. Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: Yes, you're looking for the built-in mapped type `Record<K, V>`.  I'm almost positive this is a duplicate question (looking, looking)

Comment: Also the computed property in `test` should be in brackets: `[Keys.APPLIES]: Values.GREEN`

Comment: Relevant: [What is the Record type in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936369/what-is-the-record-type-in-typescript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an enum as a dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54542318/using-an-enum-as-a-dictionary-key)

Comment: It's almost the same at least. The difference is that I want to do with an interface and not a type, don't know if it really matters though...

Comment: You can't have a mapped type as an interface, although if you have a concrete mapped type (meaning all its keys and properties are statically known and do not have an unresolved generic type parameter in it) you can extend it with an interface.  That is, `interface IFruit extends Record<Keys, Values> {}` is fine as long as `Keys` and `Values` are concrete types like you have them